# Java/Eclipse: returning to List casted Map.values()

Tags: java, eclipse, classcastexception

I'm working on a Java based web application and found suddenly a behavior which I can't understand at the moment.

Let's say I'm having the following code:

```
...snip...
Map<Integer, Foo> map = new HashMap<Integer, Foo>();
...snip...

public List<Foo> getFoos() {
    return (List<Foo>)map.values();
}
```

I know that you need to instantiate a new List like new ArrayList() for example but I wonder why eclipse is not giving me a warning.

Only when running the code I (would) get a ClassCastException. I'm quite sure that this is not a bug of eclipse as the compiler also has no problem with this code but could anyone explain me why you get always an error when running this code but IDE and compiler don't complain?

Comment: The compiler doesnt complain because ClassCastException is an unchecked exception ie. it is not checked at compile time

Comment: IntelliJ's Analyze -> Inspect Code will give you warning on this code but for the reasons Paul stated below this is valid until run time.

Answer (score 5):

Both the IDE and the compiler only inspect on a syntactical level. And on the syntactical level, everything is fine. The type of the result of `getFoos()` is of the valid type List due to the cast, and everything else is alright as well. This is actually a mistake in the semantics. On the semantic level, you are trying to cast the result of `map.values()`, which will actually return an instance of an internal type of HashMap that derives directly from AbstractCollection, to List. Since this is no valid cast (List is no supertype of the result of `map.values()`), java will throw a ClassCastException on runtime.

Answer (score 1):

According to the javadoc, [`Map.values()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()) returns a `Collection<V>`, which means that there is no guarantee that it will be `List`. This depends on the internal implementation of the specific map (in your case, the implementation of the `HashMap#values()` method returns an implementation of the `AbstractCollection` interface, called [`Values`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.Values) and this **is not** a `List`).

Better change your method's return type to `Collection<Foo>` and remove the cast.

Answer (score 0):

[`Map.values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--) is supposed return a `Collection`. Since all `List`s **are** `Collection`s, an implementation of `Map.values` could return a `List`, and the cast would be correct. At compile time there is no way to prove that the map's values `Collection` will be a `List`, but also no way to disprove it, so the compiler allows the code, but inserts a runtime check.